# Ubuntu 20.04 Server Connect to your data in the cloud: No internet connection

Tags: internet, oracle

I have a new `Ubuntu 20.04` server instance set up on Oracle.

The following all works:

- can connect to web (firefox).
- can ping a website (google.com).
- have working script that runs API with exchange.
- i can access google drive and download files (from web page).

So i believe there is a working connection.

However, when i try to connect to google drive via "online accounts" in "settings" i see that there is `No internet connection - connect to set up new online accounts`.

This is the exact screenshot:

[image]

I have been trying for 3 days now without success.

I have followed these posts:

- https://www.cyberithub.com/solved-no-internet-connection-after-installation-of-ubuntu-20-04
- [Ubuntu desktop GNOME "no Internet connection" on 19.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1155478/ubuntu-desktop-gnome-no-internet-connection-on-19-04)
- [Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Server gnome-software not working Pi4-8G](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1407301/ubuntu-22-04-lts-server-gnome-software-not-working-pi4-8g)

None have been successful. And I am now totally stuck for what I can do.

So my question is, how can i get the internet connection working ?

Comment: Do you have a desktop installed on your server? How did you do that - specifics. You may not have installed everything needed to get "Online Accounts" working.

Comment: @OrganicMarble,  yes,  i do have a desktop installed. I followed the Oracle instruction when setting up the instance and selected the Ubuntu 20.04 version. What more am i supposed to do from this point or how can i fix it ?  (if it is broken).

Comment: Restarting the network manager can't do any harm: `sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager`.

Comment: @Jos,  thanks, i tried that,  (it was actually suggested in links 1 and 3).  i also tried restarting the entire system twice `sudo reboot now` with other attempts. I believe that i am now looking for an expert to resolve this (assuming it is possible to).

Comment: There is a page with debugging hints [here](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeOnlineAccounts/Debugging).

Comment: @Jos: Appreciated, i have tried a few of those, but i am new to linux (Ubuntu) and might create more damage to the Oracle server than good by guessing.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same exact problem running Ubuntu 22.04 in `UTM` on a Macbook Pro with the M2 Max processor.

Like you, I tried [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1155478/ubuntu-desktop-gnome-no-internet-connection-on-19-04) and it didn't quite do it for me.

It asks you to replace what's in your netplan yaml file. After that failed, I reverted back to the original file, and then followed the advice [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1442889/83838).

Specifically:

> edit your netplan yaml file created by the installer and just add the line renderer: NetworkManager

Here is what my `/etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml`  looks like now:

```
# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  ethernets:
    enp0s1:
      dhcp4: true
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

I just added that last line, as a sibling element to `ethernets` and `version`.

Then I ran:

```
sudo netplan generate
sudo netplan apply
```

[image: Working internet connection in "Online Accounts"]

I hope this helps people struggling to get Ubuntu to run in a virtual machine on Apple silicon.

Comment: That worked for me, thanks a lot!